# Check if an element exist in mongodB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to check in an if statement if an array exists in dB. So far, I am checking the above statement in the cursor, but I am guessing that it slows down the query speed. My code until now is:

EDIT:
     lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open(input_file)]

```
print len(lines)
row_no = len(lines)
col_no = len(lines)
matrix = sparse.lil_matrix((len(lines), len(lines)))

no_row  = 0
counter = 0
for item in lines:
    # find from database those items which their id exists in lines list and contain a follower_list 
    for cursor in collection.find({"_id.uid": int(item)}):
        if cursor['list_followers'] is None:
                continue
        else:               
            id = cursor['_id']['uid']
            counter+=1
            print counter
            print id
            name = cursor['screenname']
            # text.write('%s \n' %name)
            followers = cursor['list_followers']    
            print len(followers)
            for follower in followers:
                try:
                    if (follower in lines) and (len(followers)>0):
                        matrix[no_row, lines.index(follower)] = 1
                        print no_row, " ", lines.index(follower), " ", matrix[no_row, lines.index(follower)]
                except ValueError:
                    continue
            no_row+=1
            print no_row

scipy.io.mmwrite(output_file, matrix, field='integer')
```

Finally I discovered that the delay was due to the creation of the sparse.lil_matrix

Comment: Not sure if I'm following the question. Are you asking for the most efficient way to see if an array field both exists in your document and does indeed have some content?

Comment: "but I am *guessing* that it slows down the query speed" - that's the problem, right there.

Comment: Yes exactly thats my problem !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest thing I can think of is implement a [sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) and query a little differently. I'll construct a sample to demonstrate:

```
{ "a" : 1 }
{ "a" : 1, "b" : [ ] }
{ "a" : 1 }
{ "a" : 1, "b" : [ ] }
{ "b" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

Essentially what you seem to be asking is to just get that last document as a match without scanning everything. This is where a different query and a sparse index helps. First the query:

```
db.collection.find({ "b.0": { "$exists": 1 } })
```

Only returns 1 item as that is the existing array with some content at it's first index position. Now the index:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "b": 1 },{ "sparse": true })
```

But due to the query nature we have to `.hint()` this:

```
db.collection.find({ "b.0": { "$exists": 1 } }).hint({ "b": 1 }).explain()
```

That gets the 1 document and only considers the 3 documents that actually have an array.